# While or For loop which one suits for which condition

Tags: java, c++, c

Some iteration code is written like this

```
while(true)                           for(int i = 0 ; i<=4;++i)
                                        {
{  
    System.out.println(i);               System.out.println(i);
   if(i==4)                                
     break;
                                          }
}
```

both have the same logic inside it take it as assumption. So which one will be faster, better to use in code and what are the implication of using any one of  it??

Comment: Your while loop will get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: sry i forgot to mention ++i in while loop

Comment: @DeepSaxena then update your post so that it will be benefit for the new visitors

Comment: The best to use in code is the one which corresponds to the coding conventions where you are programming.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is an endless loop :) (depending on the i before the loop) The second one does (almost) what you expect. Go grab a good manual about your programming language, it will explain the difference.

On another level: Loop optimizations are much better suited to for loops (AFAIK) so a "clever" compiler might generate better code for the "for" loop. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_optimization

Comment: sry i forgot to mention ++i in while loop

Comment: My comment is still valid: go grab a manual :)

Comment: **go grab a manual** if you want to answer then answer it completely so that future users will be benefited .By giving only Partial answers will be better in comment section

Answer (score 0):

They are totally different, but if their behavior was the same, never use `break;` in such situations.

The second bucle is more clear, when you have to take into consideration performance, you don't have to do it in retreat of clean code.

The second bucle is self-documented while the first you need to add a reason to add the break in order to be understandable.

Answer (score 0):

to end the while loop on the left you have to incriment `i`

EDIT : Assuming `i` is less that 4 when the loop starts

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose, use a `for` one, since you need the value of `i`. It is more understanding for maintenance. Anyway, the compiler will optimize both codes and runtime may be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your while is not an infinite loop there is no difference as far as performance is concerned. However, I personally prefer for loop as it is cleaner. Consider this:

```
int i = 0;
while (true) {
  doSomething(i++);
  if (i == 4)
    break;
}
```

which looks cleaner with

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
  doSomething(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Im using `for` whenever I know the number of itterations in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many time you want to do some operation you have to use for loop otherwise use while loop.
For example:

- If you have some array or arraylist then suppose you want to add all
  elemnts of it then you should use for loop because you know size of
  arraylist by `size()` function and know the size of array by `length`
  attribute.
- If you have resultset and you want to retrieve all rows from it then
  you should use while loop because you don't know how many element in
  resultset object.

Answer (score 0):

Neglecting the typo of your question,Assuming that you want to know which one i choose when Both `loops` are essentially doing the same thing.

The answer is **you can go for any one.**

But it's better to use `for loop` if you know how many times you want to run a `loop` as you can set the `condition` during `initialization`. And in future also it will be easy to change it if you want to extend the `iteration`.

You can prefer `while` if you are not sure for how much `iteration` you want. In your case i will go with `for loop`

Note: the answer is opinion based.